# Ionic 4, dynamic background images

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic4

I have been trying to add multiple background images in ionic 4 project. 
For static images i have creates the styles but for dynamic images is giving error in styles.

```
     <ion-content style = "--background: url('https://restcountries.eu/data/pak.svg') 0 0/100% 50% no-repeat, 
                                   url('https://restcountries.eu/data/pak.svg') 0 100%/100% 50% no-repeat">  

                               ...............Some Code........................... 

        </ion-content>
```

Currently its giving me 2 images on background. For dynamic i'm trying:

```
<ion-content style = "--background: url('{{flag1}}') 0 0/100% 50% no-repeat, 
                                   url('{{flag2}}') 0 100%/100% 50% no-repeat">  

                               ...............Some Code........................... 

        </ion-content>
```

But images are not being displayed.
Can anybody help me in doing this.
Thank you

Answer (score 4):

For dynamic image you can use:

```
[style.background-image]="'url(' + imageLink + ')'"
```

For background position add:

```
style='background: 0 0/100% 50% no-repeat'
```

to your `ion-content`

```
<ion-content [style.background-image]="'url(' + imageLink + ')'" style='background: 0 0/100% 50% no-repeat'>  

   ...............Some Code........................... 

</ion-content>
```

**UPDATE**
*For single dynamic background image:*

inside `page.scss` add:

```
ion-content{
  --background: none
}
```

inside ion-content add:

```
<ion-content 
[style.background-image]="'url(' + imageLink + ')'" 
[style.background-size]="'cover'" 
[style.background-repeat]="'no-repeat'"
>
```

This will work with ionic 4

Comment: Thanks for reply but issue is that ionic 4 changes its background while using `--background` background tag and this will provide as `background` only.

Comment: --background prop is used when you want to change shadow-Dom element properties. In this case, only background is sufficient

Comment: and i m adding  2 images but this will allow me to add only one.

Comment: i want to add only 2 images, but those images are dynamic and will be selected from api's.

Comment: i've updated the answer, but work only with 1 bg image